# How to commit a directory in CVS?

Tags: directory, cvs

I know CVS is pretty old but have to use it in company. Recently we have upgraded a library to the latest version.

Now we want to replace the old library with new library.

So basically we want to first rename the old library in CVS and then commit new library.

In short

1. In CVS server: Rename folder `/.../js/library` to `/.../js/library_legacy`.
2. To CVS server: Commit `/.../js/library` to `/.../js/`.

Comment: Have you looked at instead tagging the current revision directory, and then checking in the new library over the old.  With the tag you can always get the components back from the original revision in total using the tag.

Comment: You really need to upgrade to a modern DVCS, or at *least* subversion.  CVS is just god awful.  Anyone using it more recently than a decade ago needs their head examined.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rename directory command in CVS, as CVS doesn't know about directories, only about files.

You have several options, and what you do depends on how you want to handle "old" checkouts of revisions from before you make this change.

1. If you want "old" checkouts to get the old library in the `../../js/library` position then you should just make a copy of the old library to the new location, followed by overwriting the current location with the new library and a commit of all that.
2. If you want the old library in the new position and have the full history there, you need to copy the directory contents **in the repository** from `js/library` to `js/library_legacy`. After that check in the new library on the new position. If you checkout an older revision, you will get the old library in both checke dout to 'js/library' and 'js/library_legacy'. Depending on your build system this may or may not be a problem
3. Similar to 2, but move the directory in the repository. This will make it impossible to checkout an old revision as the old library will no longer show up in the old position where your build system probably expects it.